# data.table generating columns in non-target data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

This seems like very un-desireable behavior. Lets say I create a data.table, `a`, with columns `x` and `y`.

```
library(data.table)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
a <- data.table(x,y)
```

I want to perform some calculations on the columns of this data.table, while retaining a "clean" copy of the data. So I make a new data.table object, `b` and perform some calculations that generate new columns in data.table `b`:

```
b <- a
b[,new.var := x*y]
```

This new variable, `new.var` is showing up in BOTH data.table objects `a` and `b`. I never told `a` to create this column, it seems to be auto-added from `b`. My question is, why is this desirable behavior? Head of each data.table below:

```
> head(a)
            y          x    new.var
1:  0.1369316 -2.0992072 -0.2874478
2: -0.1074927 -0.8418876  0.0904968
3: -0.8530955 -1.3860180  1.1824057
4: -1.8503559  0.3464916 -0.6411328
5: -0.9671240 -2.7080326  2.6190034
6:  1.8149524 -1.3655645 -2.4784345
> head(b)
            y          x    new.var
1:  0.1369316 -2.0992072 -0.2874478
2: -0.1074927 -0.8418876  0.0904968
3: -0.8530955 -1.3860180  1.1824057
4: -1.8503559  0.3464916 -0.6411328
5: -0.9671240 -2.7080326  2.6190034
6:  1.8149524 -1.3655645 -2.4784345
```

Comment: `b <- copy(a)` should do it